# How can I set the color for the progress element?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Is it possible to set the color of the "bar" for the `<progress>` element in HTML (when you specify a value, the bar is filled up to the point of the value)? If so, how? `background-color` and `background` don't seem to have any effect. Is the technique cross compatible with the latest version of all browsers?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can style the color of the bar in the `<progress>` element by changing the `background` of a few browser-proprietary selectors.

In Firefox, you can use the following:

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: blue; }
```

In Chrome or Safari, you can use:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: blue; }
```

In IE10, you just need to use the `color` attribute:

```
progress { color: blue; }
```

Source: http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/

Altogether, that makes:

```css
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: blue; }
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: blue; }
progress { color: blue; }
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="25" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="50" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="75" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="100" max="100"></progress><br>
```

Comment: If the progress element had an id of 'myprogressbar', then how would you do the Chrome one? #myprogressbar{-webkit-progress-value{background:blue}} does not appear to work.

Comment: It should be `#myprogressbar::-webkit-progress-value {background: blue; }`

Comment: @nullability sorry for the bump, but I tried what you suggested (in regards to attaching it to a class) and it didn't work, could you please show me an example through JSFiddle? Not sure what to Google to find out how to do it...

Comment: if i trying to change any other color  it automatically changed as green color how to fix this

Comment: Linux Chromium, this does not work. Seems like it broke since this answer was posted. On Firefox, it does. Edit: Up to date solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21141230/3779853).

Comment: This works too. EX: <progress style="accent-color: rgb(104, 238, 104);">50</progress> IF you have the latest chrome installed.

Answer (score 33):

### Blink / Chrome

**background-color**

To color the `background-color` of a `progress` element (the part that does not increase/decrease) in WebKit browsers use the following:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: #000; width: 100%;}
```

**color**

To color the *effective* `color` of the **moving** part of a `progress` element use the following:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #aaa !important;}
```

---

### Gecko / Firefox

**background-color**

To color the `background-color` of a `progress` element (the part that does not increase/decrease) in Gecko browsers use the following:

```
progress {background-color: #000;}
```

**color**

To color the *effective* `color` of the **moving** part of a `progress` element use the following:

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar {background-color: #aaa !important;}
```

---

### Presto / Opera

I've unofficially dropped support for Opera since they've stopped developing it. For those confused and think Opera is still being developed - that is just an obviously rebranded copy of Chrome. Do *not* test browsers, test engines!

---

### Trident / Internet Explorer (and "Edge")

When Microsoft actually makes the effort they really do actually come through, this one actually makes perfect straight-forward sense.

**background-color**

```
progress {background-color: #000;}
```

**color**

```
progress {color: #aaa;}
```

### WebKit / Safari

At some point WebKit/Safari stopped working with Chrome (or vice-versa); this is tested on Safari 14.0.3 as of 2021-03-13.

**background-color**

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: #000;}
```

**color**

```
progress[value] {-webkit-appearance: none;}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #fff;}
```

---

Putting it all together, that makes:

```css
/* background: */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: black; width: 100%;}
progress {background-color: black;}

/* value: */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: green !important;}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {background-color: green !important;}
progress {color: green;}
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="25" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="50" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="75" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="100" max="100"></progress><br>
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer but needs some updates. Opera now uses Blink and is under active development. IE is no longer supported since June 15, 2022 and Edge uses Blink too. The `!important` flag should not be needed.

Answer (score 28):

```
progress {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Shockingly, this works, but also sets the background to a charcoal black.

Answer (score 10):

The preferred method going forward for modern browsers is [`accent-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color).

Used as shown:

```
progress { accent-color: blue; }
/*or*/
#ID, .class { accent-color: blue; }
```

It seems that Chrome has already dropped support for its `-webkit-progress` psuedo-selectors, and Firefox's implementation is buggy and likely to be dropped as well. `accent-color` is supported by Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and is currently the only method with [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#widget-accent), although they're still in drafting.

**Note:** Chrome (and by extension, Edge) currently automatically switches the background color from white to dark grey, depending on how bright the accent color is.

Answer (score 9):

Each browser seems to handle progress bar styling differently at the moment, and therefore you need to style it like this:

```
progress {
/* style rules */
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
/* style rules */
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
/* style rules */
} 
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
/* style rules */
}
```

`WebKit` styles for Chrome and Safari and `moz` styles for Firefox.

From here you can simply add a background colour with `background-color`.

Good Luck! Any queries, drop me a comment below.

Comment: If i do this, it does not show progress and fills whole bar with the color

Answer (score 3):

As of August 2023, this is the simplest way I've found to recolor progress bars in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. `accent-color` doesn't seem to work. But you can set `color` on the `progress` element and then reference it in the various pseudo-classes you need, so if you want progress bars in multiple colors, you only need to change one property.

```css
progress {
    color: darkmagenta;

    /* Firefox: Unfilled portion of the progress bar */
    background: lightgrey;
}

/* Firefox: Filled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: currentColor;
}

/* Chrome & Safari: Unfilled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: lightgrey;
}

/* Chrome & Safari: Filled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: currentColor;
}

/* Easily change the color */
progress.red {
    color: darkred;
}
progress.blue {
    color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<progress value=".25">25%</progress> <br/>
<progress value=".33" class="red">33%</progress> <br/>
<progress value=".5" class="blue">50%</progress>
```

You can apply more rules, like `border` and `border-radius`, to each of the selectors above to further style your progress bar, like so:

```css
progress {
    color: darkmagenta;
    height: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* Firefox: Unfilled portion of the progress bar */
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
}

/* Firefox: Filled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: currentColor;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Chrome & Safari: Unfilled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Chrome & Safari: Filled portion of the progress bar */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: currentColor;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Easily change the color */
progress.red {
    color: darkred;
}
progress.blue {
    color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<progress value=".25">25%</progress> <br/>
<progress value=".33" class="red">33%</progress> <br/>
<progress value=".5" class="blue">50%</progress>
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of the accepted answerhere  you might want to add

```
/* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140498/chrome-progressbar-doesnt-change-color/21141230#21141230)

Answer (score 0):

progress::-moz-progress-bar {background-color: #C8DED8;}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: #C8DED8;}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #E7B92A;}

progress {border-radius: 8px; overflow: hidden; height: 6px;}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).