# chrome ProgressBar doesnt change color

Tags: html, css

I got progressbar, but it doesn't change color in chrome.
Here is a code:

```
progress.xp::-webkit-progress-value:{ 
    background: #66CC33; 
}
```

I looked up for it and it seems like its ok but it doesn't work.

Maybe I cant use class in this kind of code? or in some another way?

Comment: This is not reproducable as is, can you please add a JSFIDDLE that makes this reproducable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9kw/ here :)

Comment: you can consult to this link also http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
progress.xp::-webkit-progress-value:{ 
    background: #66CC33; 
}
```

the `:` must be removed, see:

```
                                ***|
progress.xp::-webkit-progress-value { 
    background: #66CC33; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer I wanted :))

Answer (score 6):

**check the fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9kw/5/**

```
<progress class="xp" value="50" max="60"></progress>

progress.xp {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

}
progress.xp::-webkit-progress-value{
    background:red;
}
```