# How can I change the color of a progress bar using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see my code so far ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNn5b/739/)).

I am trying to change the color of the progress bar once it reaches max capacity.

How can I accomplish this?

HTML code:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<span id="characters">255 left</span>

<br>
<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="255">
</progress>
```

JS code:

```
$('textarea').keyup(updateCount);
$('textarea').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
     var max = 255;
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML= max-cs + " left..";
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = cs;
    if (event.which < 0x20) {
        return;
      }
    if (cs == max) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // make the color of progress bar red here!! 
      }     

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set color for CSS3 html5 progress element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368202/how-to-set-color-for-css3-html5-progress-element)

Comment: @hopkins-matt Not really, since there's no JS there.

Comment: @OmriAharon OP is asking how to change color. Color is changed using CSS. If OP doesn't know how to use JS to change CSS, then it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript

Comment: If you copy paste in multiple characters you can blow through your cs == max check. You probably will want to check if cs >= max and potentially do other checks to make sure you can't paste in text that would put you over your 255 limit.

Comment: @TJRockefeller thanks.. i didn't realize that. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add `progress::-webkit-progress-value` in css it changes color and also define it jquery.

```
      if(cs>=max) 
      $('#myProgress').css("background-color", "red");
```

or you can assign a class which will assign the background color like

```
      if(cs>=max) 
      $('#myProgress').addClass("red");
```

```js
$('textarea').keyup(updateCount);
$('textarea').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  var max = 255;
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    if(cs>max) $(this).val($(this).val().toString().substring(0,max));
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML= max-cs + " left..";
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = cs;
      if(cs>=max){
        $('#myProgress').addClass("red");
        }
      else{
        $('#myProgress').removeClass("red");

        }
    if (event.which < 0x20) {
        return;
      }
    if (cs >= max) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // make the color of progress bar red here!! 
      }     
      
}
```

```css
progress.red{
  background-color:red;
  color:red;
  }
progress.red[value] {color:red} /* IE10 */
progress.red::-webkit-progress-bar-value {background-color:red}
progress.red::-webkit-progress-value {background-color:red}
progress.red::-moz-progress-bar {background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<span id="characters">255 left</span>

<br>
<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="255">
</progress>
```

Comment: could you please explain why css is needed there? i dont understand why progress::-webki-progress-bar-value....  is needed there for it to turn red.. with out the css it just turns green (which also i dont understand why)...

Comment: actually light blue(unfinished) and  the green(finished atleast one time) are the default commbinations. so to override it we are using three browser standards webkit, moz, and IE(it uses color). thats why it shows the default value if you delete the css. `-webkit-progress-bar` actually denotes the background colour of the <progress>

Comment: Thank you. really liked the adding the class idea

Comment: I am glad that it that it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: So to be sure this works in most browsers you should use background-color over color.

Since you're already using JQuery:

```
$('#myProgress').css("background-color", "red");
```

pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('myProgress').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: In browser other than IE you should use 'background' or 'background-color' instead of 'color'

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
document.getElementById("myProgress").style.background = "#f3f3f3";
```

once you reach the max value

This should work fine

```
$('textarea').keyup(updateCount);
$('textarea').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
     var max = 255;
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML= max-cs + " left..";
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = cs;
    if (event.which < 0x20) {
        return;
      }
    if (cs == max) {
             document.getElementById("myProgress").style.background = "#f3f3f3";
        event.preventDefault();
        // make the color of progress bar red here!! 
      }     

}
```

Comment: This makes the progress color green for me. https://jsfiddle.net/aoqwvax2/

Answer (score 0):

Check updated snippet for this

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'textarea', updateCount);

function updateCount(event) {
    var max = 255;
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $("#characters").html(max - cs + " left..");
    $("#myProgress").val(cs);
    if (event.which < 0x20 && cs == max) {
        return;
    }
    if (cs == max) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#myProgress').addClass("red");
    } else {
        $('#myProgress').removeClass("red");
    }
}
```

```css
progress.red {
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
progress.red[value] {
    color: red
}
progress.red::-webkit-progress-bar-value {
    background-color: red
}
progress.red::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: red
}
progress.red::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<span id="characters">255 left</span>
<br>
<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="255"></progress>
```