# How to I change the color of my poll/progress bar?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have made a poll which displays two progress bars of the poll results (in percentages). I want to change the color of my progress/poll bars and center their position on the page. For centering the poll results, I tried to use 'text-align: center;' but it didn't work.

When the poll question is asked, it is centered on the page:
[image]
but when the poll bar results appear, it is positioned to the left:
[image]

I have also tried to change the color of the progress bar but nothing works so far and it just stays blue.
[image]

If you have any solutions for centering the poll results or changing the color of the poll/progress bars please help :)

HTML:

```
<script>
                    function getVote(int) {
                    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                        document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","poll/study_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    }
                </script>

                <div id="poll">
                    <h2>When studying, do you often find yourself procrastinating?</h2>
                    <form>
                    Yes: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)"><br>
                    No: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
                    </form>
                </div>
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);

$yesProgress = 100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2);
$noProgress = 100*round($no/($no+$yes),2);

?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes:</td>

        <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $yesProgress ?>">
            <?= $yesProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $yesProgress ?>%
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No:</td>
        <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $noProgress ?>">
            <?= $noProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $noProgress ?>%
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your progress bars container needs to be set to `display:inline-block` before you can use `text-align:center`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769403/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-progress-bar-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try to do :

```
<div class="div_center_table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes:</td>
      <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $yesProgress ?>">
          <?= $yesProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $yesProgress ?>%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No:</td>
      <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $noProgress ?>">
          <?= $noProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $noProgress ?>%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And in your CSS file :

```
div_center_table{
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```