# CSS accent-color opposite property?

Tags: css

In CSS `accent-color` is used to change the colour of certain form elements such as `progress`, `range inputs`, `radio inputs`, and `checkbox inputs`.

```css
input {
  accent-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

This only changes the main color though... Is there a **CSS property** to just as easily change the secondary colour?
(The secondary colour being the white background of the slider in the above example.)

I am aware that the color-scheme property exists but I am hoping for more control than just light/dark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: @savageGoat Not exactly, I am aware you can completely redo the slider but I am hoping for a simple property that can change the default slider's colours like `accent-color` can.

Comment: it seems there's no "general" property, so far, what I've found are specific pseudo-classes, for progress https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368202/how-can-i-set-the-color-for-the-progress-element and range https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/#aa-styling-the-track

Comment: There isn't, at least for now. A (very if you are into colors) insightful spec discussion around this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6159

Comment: Recap of what @kaiido just posted: `RESOLVED: Close issue, one color accent-color for now`